# tf.argsort and np.argsort gave different results

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

So I want to argmax y0, and I tested it in numpy and tensorflow 2, which results are different.
Couldn't figure out why.

```
maxy0 = np.amax(y0)
e0 = np.exp(y0 - maxy0)
p0 = e0 / np.sum(e0)
y0 = np.log(1e-20 + p0)
print(y0)
[[-46.0517 -46.0517 -46.0517 ... -46.0517 -46.0517 -46.0517]]
```

```
np.argsort(-y0)
array([[   11,     0, 26664, ..., 13337, 13330, 40001]])
```

```
tf.argsort(-y0)
array([[   11,     0,     1, ..., 39999, 40000, 40001]], dtype=int32)
```

why are they different?

Comment: You have an array of equal numbers...  since the merging algorithms used are no stable by default, there are no guarantees they should yield the same results

Comment: Like @rafaelc said, you can set stable argument in `np.argsort` and `tf.argsort`. In default, it's unstable sort.

Comment: @rafaelc  Not all numbers are equal, but majority of them, but I think your answer makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the stable argument to **True** as by default it is **False** in tf.argsort.
Please refer https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort